# How to use YAML placeholders For Java

Tags: java, yaml

I'm trying to do string replacement in JAVA using placeholders in YAML.

What kind of implementation should I implement to import the following YAML and replace the placeholders with Java source code?

```yaml
exportFile:
    exportFileNamePattern: export_${no}_${date}.zip
```

Comment: There is a myriad of text templating engines available for Java. `java.text.MessageFormat`, [mustache](https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java), [Velocity](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/index.html) and lots of others would all be viable for doing this. Therefore, this is not a good question because the choice of templating engine is rather subjective.

Comment: Thank you for answering.

I'm sorry that the question is not appropriate.

I would like to consider the template engine that you have taught me.